# Define an empty object type in Typescript, which raises error on property set or access

Tags: typescript, types

In Typescript you can't define an empty object type with `{}`. Instead, I know I can define it using `Record<string, never>` or alike. But my problem is that I want this type to raise errors when both accessing and setting properties of the empty object (because I don't want any of those things to happen in my code).

This is what I discovered so far:

```
let objA: Record<string | number | symbol, never> = {};
objA = { prop: 'value' }; // Error setting prop ✔
console.log(objA.prop); // No error accessing prop ✘
console.log(objA.nonExistingProp); // No error accessing nonExistingProp ✘

let objB: Record<never, never> = {};
objB = { prop: 'value' }; // No error setting prop ✘
console.log(objB.prop); // Error accessing prop ✔
console.log(objB.nonExistingProp); // Error accessing nonExistingProp ✔
```

As you can see, I can successfully make an empty object type that raises errors when setting OR when accessing properties, but how do I make the type raise errors on any of those at the same time? What should be the type of the `objC` variable bellow?

```
let objC: ??? = {};
objC = { prop: 'value' }; // This should be an error!
console.log(objC.prop); // This should be an error!
console.log(objC.nonExistingProp); // This should be an error!
```

Comment: `const objX = {};`?

Comment: @cprcrack  Judging by the use case of this variable and type, since it is an empty `{}` and it cannot be `get` or `set` basically you cannot provide any operation on this 
So you can do just 
`let objB: never = {} as never;` and it will throw error for all the scenarios that you have defined above